# How to remove array number

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

This is an example from my array on the following image :

[image]

I want to remove array numbers that are shown on the image. Can you help me?
My Code :

```
$addresses_list = array();
$stmt_select_address_result = $this->connect()->prepare("SELECT lat,lng,address FROM api_order where userid='$user_id';");
$stmt_select_address_result->execute();

for ($i = 0; $i < $stmt_select_address_result->rowCount(); $i++) {
      $addresses_list[$i] = $stmt_select_address_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      if (in_array($stmt_select_address_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), $addresses_list)) {
          unset($addresses_list[$i]);
      }
 }
```

Comment: these are indexes and you can replace them with strings[to make it associative array] ,but you can't remove them. check `php array` basics

Comment: @AlivetoDie Can you help me to edit my codes to remove this numbers?

Comment: What is your expected output? It's unclear from your question.

Comment: @AlivetoDie If i remove `if (in_array ...` it works ...

Comment: @Nick I said. show arrays without number. (look at image : hide red rectangle)

Comment: Why do you want to remove index. what is the purpose ?

Comment: One thing to try would be to try and remove duplicates in the SQL rather than having to post process the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that they will not be removed as they are not sequential numeric indexes, when you `json_encode()` an array, it will add the key unless they are sequential and numeric.

The way you could do it is to reverse the logic in your loop to only add ones you need...

```
while( $row = $stmt_select_address_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      if (!in_array($row, $addresses_list)) {
          $addresses_list[] = $row;
      }
 }
```